# Show hour and after minutes, without showing the window with icons in Tempus Dominus Js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I am using Rails and [bootstrap4-datetime-picker-rails](https://github.com/Bialogs/bootstrap4-datetime-picker-rails) , and it use [Tempus Dominus JS](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/) .

I want on hours select, show only hour and after show minutes, without showing the hour and minutes together.

I read the documentation but don't understand if it is possible.

I am using this code:

CoffeScript

```
$('#datetimepicker14').datetimepicker
  format: 'LT'
  inline: true
  stepping: 5
  disabledTimeIntervals: [[moment({h: 0}), moment({h: 8})], [moment({h: 18 }), moment({h: 24})]]
  disabledHours: [0]
```

html.erb

```
<%= f.input :hour, as: :string, as: :hidden, input_html: {id: 'datetimepicker14', data: {toggle: "datetimepicker", target: "#datetimepicker14"}} %>
```

First show Hours select

[image: First show Hours select]

Before show Minutes select

[image: Before show Minutes select]

Dont show it in the first time, and never show buttons up down

[image: Dont show it in the first time, and never show buttons up down]

appreciate any help.